# How is rand() calculated when used in a query with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, mysql, random, group-by

I have some SQL where i need to group some rows in a query, and use a random value for each row after grouping, so that the random value will be evenly distributed for each row after grouping, but i am not sure how mySql is handling
this

see this very simplified example:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS soldier (
     unit VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     personal_number INT
 ) 

select unit, count(name), rand()
   from soldier
   group by unit
```

so i tried to enter 3 soldiers from one unit and one soldier from another, 
and the random column seems to be distributed rather similarly in the results set. but i suspect
that what might be happening is that maybe the value for the grouped row is taken always from the smallest value soldier row, or from largest, and then the distribution would be skewed. if OTOH it is taken randomly from any of the 
grouped soldiers, or averaged, or being calculated after grouping, i am good(as far as i can tell). 
does anyone know how rand() is calculated in such cases?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: is rand() being calculated before or after grouping

Comment: seems like I was wrong all along. Refer to other answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I forgot about the basics. Your query is evaluated in this order**:

```
FROM, GROUP BY, COUNT, SELECT
```

In your example, MySQL creates two groups before select:

- Unit 1 with 3 soldiers
- Unit 2 with 1 soldier

The `RAND()` function will be called once for each row *after* grouping. Your query, in its current form, is correct.

Note than `RAND()` can safely be used inside `SELECT` because it is a function, not a column reference. And just to be sure, I replaced it with a UDF that records how many times it was called; it was called twice for your example.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a documentation reference for this, but empirically I was able to determine that MySQL appears to be evaluating `rand()` *after* the `GROUP BY` aggregation has finished.  That is, it is evaluating `rand()` once per *group*, not once per every record in the table.  I setup the following test:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 3 AS val UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 10
)

SELECT id, SUM(val) AS val_sum, rand()
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id;
```

### Demo

To verify that `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode was enabled, I changed the query to this, and it failed:

```
SELECT id, SUM(val) AS val_sum, rand(), val   -- non aggregate column = failure
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id;
```

So, your current approach is selecting random values for each group.  Note that, even if it *were* selecting random values for each record, and then choosing a certain minimum record, then the values should still be random.

Comment: right, they would still be random but the distribution will change somewhat, i think

Comment: @odedwolff No it won't...why would you expect that?  In any case, this is not even happening, so it's a moot point.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cross join and subquery eg:

```
    select a.unit, a.num, t.rand
    from (
    select unit, count(name) as num, t.rand
       from soldier
       group by unit
    ) a
    cross join (
        select rand() as rand 
        from dual
    ) t
```

Comment: It seems to select only one random value, you need to use a sub query.